# How to change the inside color of a Textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I want to change the Color of an textfield in flutter.
Means the area within the InputBorder.
I tried to wrap the textfield in container, and change the color of the container, but this seems a fool's step to solve the problem.

I tried the fillColor option, but nothing changed.

[image: Image to illustrate the situation]

Here is my Code -->

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
    10,
    screenHeight * 0.016415869,
    10,
    0,
  ),
  height: screenHeight * 0.082079343,
  child: TextField(
    cursorColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Colors.black, //Nothing Worked
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        15,
        screenHeight * 0.002735978,
        2,
        screenHeight * 0.002735978,
      ),
      hintText: "Search",
      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
        fontSize: screenHeight * 0.020519836,
        color: Color(0xFFC6C8CA),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey[200].withOpacity(0.2),
        ),
      ),
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey[200].withOpacity(1),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Add ```filled: true, ``` just before your fill color statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Try out this:-`**

```html
decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey,
```

Answer (score 2):

**don't use Container for TextField decoration, there are more property into TextField**

TextField use

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white10,
    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
        new Radius.circular(14.0),
      ),
    ),
```

```
TextField(
  controller: usernameController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white10,
    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
        new Radius.circular(14.0),
      ),
    ),
    hintText: 'Username',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white10),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
    ),
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white10),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the color to your text field then there is one boolean variable which you need to set true so your color will be added to your text field

```
             Container(
              child: TextField(
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Colors.black, // you can change color of textfield 
                  filled: true, // this should be true if you want to set color to textfield
                  hintText: "Search",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can leave your code as you provided us. The important missing value is

```
filled: true
```

With this value applied you can style the background color easy.
Reference to the doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html